# kohana 3.2 routes examples

Tags: php, routes, kohana

I have been working on routes and I cant find any examples for dummies-

Can anyone provide some for these scenarios?

lets say the site is www.site.com/test/ test is the controller with action index

Scenario 1 - someone puts www.site.com/test/one

using routing can it send them to index since controller one doesnt exist?

Scenario 2

we create controller two
we want www.site.com/test/two to take you to another controller you specify

Scenario 3

lastly we have www.site.com/test/paul/james/

how do we set it up so we get both paul and jame?

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Scenario 1** (www.site.com/test/one):

You have:

`Route::set('s1', '(<controller>(/<level2>))')
    ->defaults(array(
        'action' => 'index',
    ));`

In `test` controller you can get `one` through $this->request->param('level2').

**Scenario 2** (www.site.com/test/two):

Use:

`Route::set('s2', 'test/two')
    ->defaults(array(
        'controller' => 'two',
        'action'     => 'index',
    ));`

**Scenario 3** (www.site.com/test/paul/james/):

Use:

`Route::set('s3', 'test/<name>/<surname>')
    ->defaults(array(
        'controller' => 'test',
        'action'     => 'index',
    ));`

Yoy can access `paul` through $this->request->param('name') and `james` through $this->request->param('surname') in your `test` controller.